# Stylesheet Pack and JS Pack doesn't work - Rails 6

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

So I tried to organize my javascript and css packs as much as possible.

I have two layouts so far that separate the CSS and JS files that I need per layout accordingly.

Under javascript->packs->dashboard.js:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage")
require("channels")


require("dashboard/metisMenu.min")
require("dashboard/startmin")

import './stylesheets/dashboard.scss'
```

Under javascript->packs->application.js:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage")
require("channels")


import 'bootstrap'
import './stylesheets/application.scss'
```

Under javascript->packs->stylesheets/application.scss:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Under javascript->packs->stylesheets/dashboard.scss:

```
$fa-font-path: '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts';
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid";
@import "metisMenu.min";
@import "startmin";
```

And on my layout file views->layouts->dashboard.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'dashboard', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'dashboard', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
  <%= render 'layouts/error_messages' %>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried this approach however it seems that my javascript and CSS did not work.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you specify what is not working? Are you getting an error, or a blank js/css file etc?